# UriFormatException: Absolute URI is too short in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, uri, absolute, short

I am building a unity project but it gives me below errors :

```
UriFormatException: Absolute URI is too short
System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String uriString)
System.Uri.ParseUri (UriKind kind)
System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape)
System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString)
System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.String requestUriString)
UnityEditor.CrashReporting.CrashReporting.GetUsymUploadAuthToken () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Src/CloudServicesSettings/CrashReporting/Managed/CrashReporting.cs:95)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Error building Player: UriFormatException: Absolute URI is too short

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00207] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:172 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean building the project in Visual Studio or building in Unity? Are you using the WWW class?

Comment: I am building the project in Unity. I am using WWW classes in my scripts but the error does not point to any of those scripts.

Comment: Post the relevant code from the two classes giving the error, please

Comment: Specifically, what is the URI?

Comment: Actually, there is no description of code line where this error is hitting. So, I can't know which line of code this giving this error